Allow user to simply select an account rather than having to type in their Microsoft credentials everytime (Flutter, MSAL, AAD_OAUTH)
I was curious how I would be able to allow a user that just signed out of my app to click the Sign In button and have a screen like below appear.

When a user signs out of my app, it requires them to have to re-enter their Microsoft credentials from scratch, whereas the app that I'm trying to mimic has somehow stored your previously signed in accounts and remembered as pictured above.
I'm writing my app using Flutter and the package for authentication that I'm using is aad_oauth and this is what I have for the configuration of my AadOauth instance.
auth_service.dart
static final Config config = Config(
    tenant: '...',
    clientId: '...',
    scope: "${dotenv.env['AppScope']!} openid profile offline_access user.read",
    redirectUri: (Platform.isAndroid)
        ? dotenv.env['androidRedirectUri']!
        : dotenv.env['iOSRedirectUri'],
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    // webUseRedirect: true, // default is false - on web only, forces a redirect flow instead of popup auth
    loader: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    // postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://your_base_url/logout', //optional
  );

  final AadOAuth oauth = AadOAuth(config);

class AuthService extends ChangeNotifier {
  // TODO: Should move the clientId + tenantId to .env file?
  static final Config config = Config(
    tenant: '...',
    clientId: '...',
    scope: "${dotenv.env['AppScope']!} openid profile offline_access user.read",
    redirectUri: (Platform.isAndroid)
        ? dotenv.env['androidRedirectUri']!
        : dotenv.env['iOSRedirectUri'],
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    // webUseRedirect: true, // default is false - on web only, forces a redirect flow instead of popup auth
    loader: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    // postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://your_base_url/logout', //optional
  );

  final AadOAuth oauth = AadOAuth(config);

  bool _isLoadingUser = true;
  bool get isLoadingUser => _isLoadingUser;
  set setIsLoadingUser(bool value) {
    _isLoadingUser = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool _isAuthenticated = false;
  bool get isAuthenticated => _isAuthenticated;

  AuthService();

  Future<void> initializeAuthService() async {
    try {
      if (await hasCachedAccountInformation()) {
        log('User is already authenticated');
        await oauth.refreshToken();
        _isAuthenticated = true;
      } else {
        log('User is not authenticated');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      log('Error initializing AuthService: $e');
    } finally {
      _isLoadingUser = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  // Changed to Future<void>, see: https://www.reddit.com/r/dartlang/comments/maxl6y/futurevoid_versus_void_for_async_function_return/
  Future<void> login() async {
    final result = await oauth.login();
    result.fold(
      (l) => log(l.toString()),
      (r) => log('Logged in successfully, your access token: $r'),
    );
    var accessToken = await oauth.getAccessToken();
    if (accessToken != null) {
      log('Access token: $accessToken'); // TODO: Delete?
      _isLoadingUser = false;
      _isAuthenticated = true;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    try {
      log('Logging out'); // TODO: Delete
      await oauth.logout();
      _isAuthenticated = false;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      log('Error logging out: ${e.toString()}');
    }
  }

  Future<bool> hasCachedAccountInformation() async {
    var hasCachedAccountInformation = await oauth.hasCachedAccountInformation;
    log('HasCachedAccountInformation: $hasCachedAccountInformation'); // TODO: Delete
    return hasCachedAccountInformation;
  }

  Future<String?> getCachedAccessToken() async {
    var accessToken = await oauth.getAccessToken();
    log('Got Access token: $accessToken'); // TODO: Delete
    return accessToken;
  }

  refreshToken() async {
    return await oauth.refreshToken();
  }
}

auth_gate.dart (file that shows the Sign in page)
class AuthGate extends StatelessWidget {
  AuthGate({super.key});

  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
      // User is not authenticated
      return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        return Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ...
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await showAlertDialog(
                      context, authService, isMobileWidth);
                },
                child: Text(
                  'SIGN IN',
                  style: isMobileWidth
                      ? primaryButtonText
                      : primaryButtonText.copyWith(
                          fontSize: tabletFontSize,
                        ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
        });
  }

  showAlertDialog(
    ...
    // set up the buttons
    Widget cancelButton = TextButton(
      child: Text(
        "Cancel",
        style: bodyRegular.copyWith(
            fontSize: isMobileWidth ? mobileFontSize : tabletFontSize),
      ),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(), // dismiss dialog,
    );
    Widget continueButton = TextButton(
      child: Text(
        "Continue",
        style: bodyRegular.copyWith(
            fontSize: isMobileWidth ? mobileFontSize : tabletFontSize),
      ),
      onPressed: () async {
        authService.setIsLoadingUser = true;
        Navigator.of(context).pop(); // dismiss dialog
        await authService.login();
        authService.setIsLoadingUser = false;
      },
    );

    // Android Alert Dialog
    AlertDialog androidAlert = AlertDialog(
      title: Text(
        alertDialogTitle,
        style: bodyRegular.copyWith(
          fontSize: isMobileWidth
              ? mobileDialogTitleFontSize
              : tabletDialogTitleFontSize,
        ),
      ),
      content: Text(
        alertDialogContent,
        style: bodyRegular.copyWith(
          fontSize: isMobileWidth
              ? mobileDialogDescriptionFontSize
              : tabletDialogDescriptionFontSize,
        ),
      ),
      actions: [
        cancelButton,
        continueButton,
      ],
    );

    // iOS Alert Dialog
    CupertinoAlertDialog iOSAlert = CupertinoAlertDialog(
      title: Text(
        alertDialogTitle,
        style: bodyRegular.copyWith(
          fontSize: isMobileWidth
              ? mobileDialogTitleFontSize
              : tabletDialogTitleFontSize,
        ),
      ),
      content: Text(
        alertDialogContent,
        style: bodyRegular.copyWith(
          fontSize: isMobileWidth
              ? mobileDialogDescriptionFontSize
              : tabletDialogDescriptionFontSize,
        ),
      ),
      actions: [
        cancelButton,
        continueButton,
      ],
    );

    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        if (Platform.isIOS) {
          return iOSAlert;
        } else {
          return androidAlert;
        }
      },
    );
  }
}


Can you share your complete code in the question or share your GitHub repo?

@DasariKamali I went ahead and edited my post to include a bit more of my code that's relevant to signing in if that helps :)

It doesn't look like the package (aad_oauth) supports select_account as a value for prompt officially but where would I add what you said in my request to do that?

For anyone curious, I did end up creating a PR to implement this feature for mobile devices in the original package used (https://pub.dev/packages/aad_oauth) as select_account seemed to have worked for a flutter web app but not for when it was on mobile.
That being said, a new release with those changes isn't out so I created a fork of the repo and began using that as a package dependency instead. Here's a link to the fork: https://github.com/paulhwangfti/aad_oauth
The way that you would then use it within your project is shown below:
pubspec.yml
dependencies:
  dynatrace_flutter_plugin: 3.291.1
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  ...
  aad_oauth:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/paulhwangfti/aad_oauth.git
      ref: 1.0.2 // most recent version i have out as of making this post

and if you run into issues with local development, these are some commands I needed to run:

